# How to change text of "file" <Input> antd

Tags: reactjs, input, text, antd, placeholder

I believe the title is self-explanatory. I have checked the docs and some other threads, but I simply cannot manage to change both texts of the label: nor "Choose file", neither "No file chosen". Below is what I have tried so far. How could I change those texts? [image]

```js
 {/* <label htmlFor="test" id="files">Test with classic label</label> */}
                  <Input
                  // addonAfter="test1"
                  // addonBefore="test2"
                    type="file"
                    onChange={handleFileSelected}
                    text="test"
                  />
```

Answer (score 2):

The text of the input's file element is controlled by the browser so you can not directly change that. What you can do is instead creating a customizable button that uses a ref to control the click on the input:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

```
<button onClick={() => ref.current?.click()}>Click Here</button>
<input 
 type='file' 
 ref={ref} 
 onChange={handleFileSelected}
 style={{ display: "none" }} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Ant Design also has [Upload component](https://ant.design/components/upload/#header) for file uploading which could be styled easily